# What tree is that, judging by seeds?

Tags: identification, trees, seeds

I've found a tree while on stroll with no leaves (naturally - it's early spring after all). What amused me is that it was filled with things (on photo) that supposedly contain the seeds. Unfortunately, I didn't take a photo of the tree itself. Is there a way to identify what tree is that? That's in Saint Petersburg, Russia.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like these seeds are from an *Acer*, based on the "helicopter" structure.
To be able to tell the species you will need more information, pictures of the leaves or from less dried up seeds.

Comment: AKA ; maple ( and boxelder ).

Comment: Those could also be ash seeds, which look very similar to maple (Acer) seeds. See [this picture](https://www.dreamstime.com/dry-branches-ash-tree-dry-branches-ash-tree-seeds-image101425975), [this picture](https://www.dreamstime.com/dry-ash-tree-fraxinus-seeds-twig-covered-snow-blurry-background-dry-ash-tree-fraxinus-seeds-twig-covered-snow-image141319399), and [this picture](https://www.dreamstime.com/close-up-snow-covered-ash-tree-branch-dangling-seeds-lionfishes-several-image130393318). It would help to have a picture of the tree's branches and bark to help differentiate ash from maple.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Thank you! One of the seeds did germinate so hopefully I'll be able to tell the species once it grows a bit.